# Rank by grouby column aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a column `manager_rank` that ranks a manager by the `sum` of returns. I have come up with one solution posted below but was hoping if someone else had something more elegant.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2012', 'A', 1], ['2012', 'B', 4], ['2011', 'A', 5], ['2011', 'B', 4]],
                 columns=['year', 'manager', 'return'])
```

Desired result:

```
   year manager  return  manager_rank
0  2012       A       1             2
1  2011       A       5             2
2  2012       B       4             1
3  2011       B       4             1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df['ranking'] = df.groupby('manager')['return'].transform(np.sum).rank(ascending=False, method='dense')

   year manager  return  ranking
0  2012       A       1        2
1  2012       B       4        1
2  2011       A       5        2
3  2011       B       4        1
```

Answer (score 2):

### One-liner:

```
manager_rank = (df.groupby('manager')
                  .sum()
                  ['return']
                  .rank(ascending=False)
                  .to_frame(name='manager_rank')
                  .reset_index()
                )

df = pd.merge(df, manager_rank, on='manager')
```

### Step By Step Details:

#### 1. Group by Manager with `sum` as aggregation function

```
In [8]: df.groupby('manager').sum()
Out[8]: 
         return
manager        
A             6
B             8
```

#### 2. Use `rank()` assign ranks to managers

```
In [9]: df.groupby('manager').sum().rank()
Out[9]: 
         return
manager        
A             1
B             2

In [10]: df.groupby('manager').sum().rank(ascending=False)
Out[10]: 
         return
manager        
A             2
B             1
```

#### 3. Cast this result to another column

```
In [13]: df.groupby('manager').sum().rank(ascending=False)['return'].to_frame(name='manager_rank')
Out[13]: 
         manager_rank
manager              
A                   2
B                   1
```

#### 4. Join the result of above steps with original data frame!

```
df = pd.merge(df, manager_rank, on='manager')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `to_frame` and add `name` to [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
manager_rank = (df.groupby('manager')
                  .sum()
                  ['return']
                  .rank(ascending=False)
                  .reset_index(name='manager_rank')
                )

df = pd.merge(df, manager_rank, on='manager')
print df

   year manager  return  manager_rank
0  2012       A       1             2
1  2011       A       5             2
2  2012       B       4             1
3  2011       B       4             1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about extending the method proposed by @Stefan to include the final cumulative return of each manager (returns don't sum, they compound).

```
df['total_return'] = (df
                      .groupby('manager')['return']
                      .transform(lambda group: (1 + group / 100.).cumprod().iat[-1])) - 1
df['ranking'] = df.total_return.rank(ascending=False, method='dense')

>>> df
   year manager  return  ranking  total_return
0  2012       A       1        2        0.0605
1  2012       B       4        1        0.0816
2  2011       A       5        2        0.0605
3  2011       B       4        1        0.0816
```

Comment: That's an awesome way to show cumulative return. I should have named the column return_pct :-(.

Comment: That's a great answer to a different question.