# How to find the rank of groupby Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I am having trouble trying to find a simple way to rank the product's values grouped by Date and Product. For example, in June 2020, we have 6 products, they have different values, I want to rank them according to their market share out of the total, in any case, this is equivalent to ranking them according to their values.

I attempted to use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498930/rank-by-grouby-column-aggregate)'s answer but it is not giving the correct input.

I could jolly well turn this df into a 2d list and sort using a for loop, but I would say since I am using pandas, I will try my best to stick with the functionalities like `.rank()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Market'] = ['usa'] *2 + ['russia']*2 + ['china'] * 8
df["Product"] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"] * 2
df["Date"] = ["1/6/2020"] * 6 + ["1/9/2020"] * 6
df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype("datetime64[ns]")
df["Value"] = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 1000, 2000, 800, 900, 999, 10000] 


  Product   Date       Value   Expected Ranking
0   A        1/6/2020   100    1
1   B        1/6/2020   200    2 
2   C        1/6/2020   300    3
3   D        1/6/2020   400    4
4   E        1/6/2020   500    5
5   F        1/6/2020   600    6
6   A        1/9/2020   1000   3
7   B        1/9/2020   2000   2
8   C        1/9/2020   800    6
9   D        1/9/2020   900    5
10  E        1/9/2020   999    4
11  F        1/9/2020   10000  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pass `dense`

```
df.groupby('Date')['Value'].rank(method='dense')
Out[224]: 
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     4.0
4     5.0
5     6.0
6     6.0
7     5.0
8     4.0
9     3.0
10    2.0
11    1.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Oh wow... simplicity prevails I guess, you don't even need to use groupby...

Comment: Hi, It actually doesn't work if the values are different, I have edited the question.